# How to convert a linked object into an individual object?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

Iam trying to use the subdivision modifier, I selected the linked image by Shortcut Key "L" and the I go to modifier tab and select sub.divide modifier and it sub divide the whole object so If anybody how to convert a linked object into an individual object please let me know?

Comment: if you're talking about several different meshes within the same object, if you give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier, the whole object will be subdivided

Answer (score 2):

It's just vocabulary, but your question is ambiguous.

- If you want to make an **instanced** object, (one which shares some aspect of its data (mesh, materials,etc., with other objects,) independent, that's now hidden in *Header* menu *> Object > Relations > Make Single User*.
- A Subdivision Surface modifier always affects the entire object to which it is assigned. If you want to split part of the mesh off to another object, select that part of the mesh in Edit mode, and <kbd>P</kbd> *Separate > Selection*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the loose part or linked part and separate it using "P" and separate selected. Then you can apply the subdivision.